# word for "for one's own survival'

Tags: single-word-requests

In a novel I am writing, one of the characters wishes to express her change in feelings towards another.

> “I’m not asking for her sake, but for ours,” I say honestly. A few days ago, I cared about what happened to her. I almost viewed her as an ally, so my concern wasn’t merely __________. But, I have no sentiment for her anymore.

So, I would like a word that means could fill in the blank. Something that means survival-based, or for one's own survival, (sorry for my poor expression here). I'm near positive there is a word for this; I've heard it before. But, right now, the only word I think of is pathological, which means obsessive/compulsive, and that is not the word I need. One-look's reverse dictionary bore no results. If anyone could assist that would be great?

Comment: "selfish" seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Or, less pejorative, *self-interest[ed]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might go with ***self-preservation***:

> The protection of oneself from harm ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/self-preservation))

This fits in your blank as follows:

> I almost viewed her as an ally, so my concern wasn’t merely self-preservation.

It seems to meet your desiderata of something "survival-based" and "for one's own survival."